# Android Wear HorizontalScrollView doesn't have a closing tag

Tags: android, xml, mobile, horizontalscrollview

I have to add a `HorizontalScrollView` in my android wear client. Normally, on the handset, we'll have

```
<HorizontalScrollView
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView2"
     android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom" />
```

and with the closing tag `</HorizontalScrollView>`.
In the wear project, I noticed the horizontalScrollView doesn't have a closing tag. Does anyone know how does that work on the wear? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a closing tag for the `HorizontalScrollView` on Android-Wear as well, but in the sample code you've shared with us the *HorizontalScrollView* is already closed via `/>`.
So to clear things up:

`/>`

is equal to:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

With the only difference that you can't place views within the ScrollView when you're writing `/>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <your package name
            android:id="@+id/horizontal_listview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#ddd" />
```

try this. I think I may works out for you. Add HorizontialListView.class in that package . Add the above lines of code in your xml file.

Comment: http://pastie.org/9590145  here is HorizontialListView.class copy this class and paste in your package.